# c# linq question about multiple where clauses

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to query a database with multiple where clauses.

```
     IQueryable<string> statusQuery = from m in _context.Flight
                                         where m.Aircraft_Type == aircraftType
                                     && m.Identification_Registration == registration
                                     && m.Destination_Airport_City == to1
                                      && m.DepartureDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == date1
                                     && m.Origin_Airport_City == from1
                                         orderby m.Status_Text
                                         select m.Status_Text;
```

This code is working, but only if I am able to supply a value to each variable.
How can I use this with a check if e.g registration == null => do not check use

```
   && m.Identification_Registration == registration
```

if(...) doesn't work here.

Comment: from m in _context.Flight.OrderBy(x => 
 orderby x.Status_Text) where m.Aircraft_Type == aircraftType
 && m.Identification_Registration == registration
 && m.Destination_Airport_City == to1
 && m.DepartureDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == date1
 && m.Origin_Airport_City == from1
 select m.Status_Text;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can emulate this behavior using logical operators:

```
IQueryable<string> statusQuery = 
    from m in _context.Flight
    where m.Aircraft_Type == aircraftType
       && (registration == null || m.Identification_Registration == registration)
       && m.Destination_Airport_City == to1
       && m.DepartureDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == date1
       && m.Origin_Airport_City == from1
       orderby m.Status_Text
       select m.Status_Text;
```

Comment: Well, depending on what `_context` is (more particularly, which Entity Framework version is involved) it may be much better to build the predicate conditionally using a predicate builder.

Comment: Thanks Mureinik, that is working perfectly for my project.